# Recover Word Document after deleting Recovery Files

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I forgot to save my Word Document overnight and the computer shut down. Upon re-opening, Word asked me if I want to keep the Recovery Files. I clicked *No*.

Is there any chance I can still recover my document from last night?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I could recover that document. Here are the steps:

1. a) Open the recycle bin, find the `.asd` file with the right title and modification date, and restore it. Write down its file path (or copy it into a text file). (This worked for me.)

   b) Search your user directory for any `.asd` files with the right title and modification date. Note the file path.
2. Open Word. Go to File > Info > Manage Document > Recover Unsaved Documents
3. Navigate to the restored file, highlight it, and click *Open*
4. Save it in a location where you can find it again.

I got this approach (except for step 1) from [EaseUS](https://www.easeus.com/mac-file-recovery/recover-word-file-after-accidentally-clicked-don't-save.html).